# CSS position: absolute with position: relative "top" not working

Tags: css, css-position

I'm working on a site that uses position: relative div containing position: absolute divs.  I understand the concept I believe, and everything works great except I cannot seem to get the `top` attribute to do anything.  left works, but not top. My code is as follows:

```html
<div id="imagemenu">
    <div class="west">
        <img src="/makingmusicstore/wp-content/themes/makingmusic/img/west.png" alt="west">
    </div>
    <div class="southwest">
        <img src="/makingmusicstore/wp-content/themes/makingmusic/img/southwest.png alt=" southwest ">
    </div>
    <div class="south ">
        <img src="/makingmusicstore/wp-content/themes/makingmusic/img/south.png " alt="south ">
    </div>
    <div class="logo ">
        <img src="/makingmusicstore/wp-content/themes/makingmusic/img/logo.png " alt="Making Music Store ">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#imagemenu {
    position: relative;
}
.logo img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
}
.west img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    left: 15%;
}
.southwest img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    left: 15%;
}
.south img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
}
```

The site is adams-web.net/makingmusicstore and is currently a mess until I can get the top attribute to work.  It seems to me that the logo should be much further down the page, but it is not working as I believe it should.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  It does work when I change the position to static, but it doesn't keep the position correctly.

Comment: You never got the website up? I went to check it to see what you did but. Did you take it down or not get it working?

Answer (score 25):

Define your parent **div height**, and then use top `%` in top `absolute` **div**

Like this:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

If you don't define your parent div height then use `px value in top`.

```css
.child {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Of course!  Thanks for your response, I worked on this for a very long time, and the answer was so easy.

Answer (score 6):

Add `width` and `height` to `#imagemenu`

For example:

```css
#imagemenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Then check again if `position: absolute` is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Include `height:100vh;` for the parent div having `position: relative;`

**CSS**

```
#imagemenu {
    position: relative;
    height:100vh;
}
.logo img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
}
.west img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    left: 15%;
}
.southwest img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
    left: 15%;
}
.south img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35%;
}
```